# cover object in beaded strings?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, splines

I am trying to create an object covered in stringed beads, similar to mardi gras beads but I'm having some problems,

[image: reference image]

First, I start with a cube with the default bounce spline applied, now add UV sphere with a default array modifier set to like 40, now I want to use the curve modifier to align this array of spheres along the bounce spline like beads. This should work theoretically as I have done it before, yet now after hours of trying I just cannot get them to do anything other than dramatically distort in undesirable shapes. I have tried rotating them in several axes, moving them, scaling them, this does align them sometimes, but they remain terribly distorted. Does anybody wanna give it a shot, or has anybody attempted something similar? I'd appreciate any help I can get in figuring out if there's any method to this madness.

I did not include a blender file, but I thought the setup was very rudimentary, and including a blend file would have felt a bit superfluous.
Edit: bounce spline is part of  *Add Curves: Extra Object add-on* that comes with blender.

Comment: *"I start with a cube with the default bounce spline applied..."* - What is a default bounce spline?

Comment: a bounce spline with no settings edited.

Comment: Ah, I see! .... no, seriously I didn't know the *Knot > Bounce Spline*. It's part of the *Add Curves: Extra Object* add-on that comes with Blender. You should mention *that* ;-)

Comment: Have you applied the scale to the sphere object? I've tried with the default cube + default bounce spline + Array & Curve modifiers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8m0f.jpg

Comment: that look amazing blunder, just the effect i was going for, im gonna try applying scale when i get home and i'll see if it gets as good. also thanks i'll edit the post.

Comment: [Likewise](https://imgur.com/a/RJ0ZghW).. I did get a bit of a buggy response early on,  a bit too much for my machine? I built up in steps.. fewer bounces to more.. simple bead to more complex, and it seemed to be OK.

Comment: it looks really good with the material you've added. and thanks for the tips robin i'll try it out.